# QNetworkAccessManager upload to local FTP server

Tags: c++, qt, ftp, qnetworkaccessmanager, qtnetwork

I can download from the server but I can't upload to it. It uploads the file but it's an empty file.

This is basically what I'm doing:

```
QString filename="Data.txt";
QFile file( filename );
file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
file.write("HELLO") ;

QUrl urlup("ftp://127.0.0.1/file.txt");
urlup.setPassword("123");
urlup.setUserName("user");
urlup.setPort(21);
QNetworkAccessManager *nam = new QNetworkAccessManager;
QNetworkRequest requp(urlup);
nam->put(requp,&file);
file.close();
```

but it's not working; just uploads an empty file.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `127.0.0.1` use `localhost`

Instead of `setPort` append `:PortNumber` to url. (For example `ftp://localhost:21`)

Answer in this link: [Putting large size file on FTP using QNetworkAccessManager](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/51348-Putting-large-size-file-on-FTP-using-QNetworkAccessManager)

Comment: What when the link goes dead? Please when you have time, try to *at least* copy the explanation here. Best would be if you'd taken time to extend it. It actually took me a while and I didn't find the explanation.

Comment: @Tomáš Zato There is an example in the link, and this is too much long to copy here. You only need copy the code on the question and replace parts I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Try `file.flush();` after write.

Comment: Hmm, well may be you should seek to the beginning of the file before you send contents. Trying my luck last time:)

Comment: Doesn't `file.close();` run a flush? I think it does.

Comment: @M M., file.close(); runs flush indeed!

Reimplemented from QIODevice::close().
Calls QFile::flush() and closes the file. Errors from flush are ignored.