# To transfer files to device using FTP, is it necessary to have a server running on it?

Tags: linux, qt, ftp

For some time now I've been trying to send files to a Embedded Linux device via FTP without success. I even previously put [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29497160/error-occuring-when-trying-to-upload-file-via-ftp-using-qt) in SO talking about my problem, and I still haven't got any further in solving it.

One thing I noticed, though, is that most FTP examples in the web includes a server-client relationship; the client connects itself to the server that is constantly listening in some IP-Port and the file transfer begins. Now when studying the examples using QNetworkAcessManager to send a file (generally to HTTP), they never mentioned the "other side requirements", what is leading me to believe I'm missing the necessary FTP server running in my Embedded Linux device.

So my question is more like a confirmation of my suspicions: if I want to transfer a file from my Desktop to my device using FTP, do I need to have a FTP server constantly running on that device? If yes, how that should change my code? For instance, should I abandon QNetworkAcessManager in favour of a QTcpClient usage? IOW what else should I know to make the file transfer system work using Qt? (In fact should I even bother myself with FTP at all instead of just using a [normal QTcpServer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BSdKkZNEKlQ)?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FTP is a protocol with 2 parties, the client and the server. Both must comply to the specification of FTP before file transfer can take place.

So yes there has to be a FTP deamon (the server) running the on the other device.

It doesn't have to run constantly just whenever you want to transfer files.

Comment: points for specifying "doesn't have to run constantly".  While having a "set it and forget it" server is useful, sometimes you don't always want a port open